# Adding const to function template pointer argument

Tags: c++, function, templates, constants

Consider:

```
template<typename X>
inline typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer<X>::value, void>::type
replyOk(X pointer)
{
    *pointer = *pointer; //for sake of example
}
```

Is it possible to add constness to the pointed data so that *pointer = *pointer creates a compiler error.

For example I can do

```
...
replyOk(X const pointer)
...
```

But this adds constness to the variable pointer not what it points to. I'm not sure that even makes sense...

Comment: what about static_assert ? (I not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve here)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point of the `enable_if`.

```
template<typename X>
inline void replyOk(const X* pointer) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: [Not quite equivalent](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/015f2a2ec5c39a1e) but, assuming the OP only really cares about object pointers, this is much better. KISS.

Comment: Indeed that work fine, but that tells me I'm missing some basic concept about how the type resolution with template works.  If I remove the * it still works fine!  But there is a difference. The typeid of X and pointer changes. Without the *, X is pointer,  but with the * , X it is. I was not excepted that.  Thanks.